# Django - ChoiceField - Option Buttons instead of Select box

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is it possible to display the option buttons instead of select box (in the admin interface) for `ChoiceField`? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following `ModelAdmin` subclass (in your admin.py) does what you're after:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    radio_fields = {"group": admin.VERTICAL}
```

`HORIZONTAL` is also possible.

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.radio_fields).

Answer (score 1):

There's a [snippet on djangosnippets](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/200/) that seems to do something like this for forms given a list of choices, but it doesn't seem to specifically do it for the admin app.  You might be able to either leverage this or the ideas within it to get you the rest of the way though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In your admin.py create a ModelAdmin class:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect ## originally had mistake of django.forms.extras.widgets

class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
         models.ChoiceField : dict(widget = RadioSelect) 
     }

admin.site.register(SomeModel, SomeModelAdmin)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "option buttons" rather than select box, but this is how you change it.  You can find the right widget here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: Cool, did not know about the extra widgets library

Comment: It seems to not working. receiving the error "name 'RadioSelect' is not defined"

Comment: My bad; RadioSelect is in the normal forms library (django.forms.widgets) ; not forms.extras.widgets