# Django - models.CharField- choices - Option Buttons instead of Select box

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

For  `models.CharField()`, we use to give a `choices` attribute. Normally these choices will be displayed in select box. Is it possible to display the option buttons instead of select box (in admin interface)? Any suggestions?

```
status = models.CharField(max_length = 25, choices = (('IN PROGRESS', 'IN PROGRESS'),('COMPLETED','COMPLETED')))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - ChoiceField - Option Buttons instead of Select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227147/django-choicefield-option-buttons-instead-of-select-box)

Comment: We don't have ChoiceField in models class. This question is about the choices option in models.CharField.

Comment: Are questions considered a duplicates if they have the same answers? Personally, I think not but that might not be the general consensus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following ModelAdmin subclass (in your admin.py) does what you're after:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    radio_fields = {"group": admin.VERTICAL}
```

HORIZONTAL is also possible.

From the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.radio_fields).